# Python Fabric: filter out server output when capturing output of run()

Tags: python, fabric, bash

Consider a Linux server which has the following line in the `.bash_profile` of your user:

```
echo "Hello world"
```

So, every time you ssh into it, you see `Hello world`

Now, consider the following [fabric](/questions/tagged/fabric) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = [...]

@task
def test():
    with cd('/'):
        print run('ls').split()
```

You'd expect it to output something like: 
    `['tmp', 'etc', 'var', ...]`

But the actual output will be:
    `['Hello', 'world', 'tmp', 'etc', 'var', ...]`

Is this a bug in [fabric](/questions/tagged/fabric)? Is there any way to suppress server output?

`time.sleep()` does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric executes the remote Bash shell [in login mode](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/faq.html#why-do-i-sometimes-see-err-stdin-is-not-a-tty). This causes profile files to be executed. You may see this for yourself by turning on debug mode. On my machine executing your script in debug mode produces the following (among other things)

```
[x.x.x.x] Executing task 'test'
[x.x.x.x] run: /bin/bash -l -c "cd / && ls"
```

Notice the `-l` passed to the remote [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) invocation
To overcome this you may override `env.shell` to remove the `-l` flag as stated in the linked FAQ.

So change

```
with cd('/'):
```

in your code to

```
with cd('/'), settings(shell='/bin/bash -c'):
```